# KeyPairGeneration not working in java for RSA

Tags: java, security, rsa

I am trying to get private keys and public keys for RSA encryption in java using java.security. No matter where i google I keep getting same error saying NoSuchAlgorithException.

```
class secret {
    void secret(){
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey pubkey = kp.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privkey = kp.getPrivate();
        System.out.println(privkey.getEncoded()+"---"+pubkey.getEncoded());
    }
}
```

This is my secret class which implemets key derivation for RSA. This is my main

```
class project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        secret sec = new secret();
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
javac project.java
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
project.java:11: error: unreported exception NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                                                                   ^
1 error
```

Comment: After doing the edits mentioned by @User913 , here is my code : https://pastebin.com/jDP56TSc and i still get Unresolved compilation problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method KeyPairGenerator#getInstance define as

```
public static KeyPairGenerator getInstance(String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
```

NoSuchAlgorithmException is a [checked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). You must handle it:

```
static void secret(){
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = null;
    try {
        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey pubkey = kp.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privkey = kp.getPrivate();
    System.out.println(privkey.getEncoded()+"---"+pubkey.getEncoded());
}
```

Comment: I just had to add an exception! I was thinking there is some issue with my code. For those facing the same issue, just add the exception. Consider it as a part of syntax!

Comment: I now get error saying .encoding=UTF-8 -cp /root/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/5af4ffaafdad5a6d80277fc1baad21a4/redhat.java/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin project 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

        at project.main(project.java:29)

Comment: How do you compile it? I copy your code and its compile normally

Comment: 1) javac learning/project.java 2) java -cp . learning.project

Comment: There is this directory called Project inside which is project.class,project.java and secret.class. I am inside Project directory and doing javac project.java and then doing java -cp . project . I have same error!

Comment: Remove your *.class files. Your package named as "learning". Project structure must look like as Project/learning/project.java. Go to Project directory and run "javac learning/project.java". Do you have some error ?